# Generating a poster based on a template

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to create functionality on a webshop where posters are sold. The webshop uses Wordpress with Woocommerce.

Please take a look at the following picture
[image]

It shows a template for a poster and I want to be able to automatically generate the appropriate poster based on user input. This means there should be the following fields:

- Time
- Date
- First name
- Middle name
- Last Name
- Height
- Weight

The user should also be able to add figures in the two figure areas by choosing from a certain amount of figures.

The user should be able to see the poster change in a preview and when he is happy the user must add it to his basket and finally, when/if he chooses to buy it. The poster should be send to a certain email-address with the ordernumber included.

Obviously I don't intent or expect anyone to come up with an entire solution but what I need is a way to get started and I have single quesiton.

The poster-generation with a real-time preview: What technology would be fit for the task? Which technologies should I start to research on to be able to make the wanted functionality?

In my current research i've found something called iTextSharp, but it looks like it only works with either JAVA or C# and I need this to work on a website running wordpress so I guess PHP needs to be involved in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an image in php and add text to it:

```
<?php
$my_img = imagecreate( 200, 80 );
$background = `enter code here`imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 0, 0, 255 );
$text_colour = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 255, 255, 0 );
$line_colour = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 128, 255, 0 );
imagestring( $my_img, 4, 30, 25, "thesitewizard.com", $text_colour );
imagesetthickness ( $my_img, 5 );
imageline( $my_img, 30, 45, 165, 45, $line_colour );

header( "Content-type: image/png" );
imagepng( $my_img );
imagecolordeallocate( $line_color );
imagecolordeallocate( $text_color );
imagecolordeallocate( $background );
imagedestroy( $my_img );
?>
```